# NSAttributedKey UIAccessibilitySpeechAttributeQueueAnnouncement

Tags: ios, swift, uiaccessibility

I would liked to post a queued announcement

I tried using `UIAccessibilitySpeechAttributeQueueAnnouncement` but I have trouble converting it into an `NSAttributedStringKey`

## Code:

```
let queueAnnouncementKey = NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: UIAccessibilitySpeechAttributeQueueAnnouncement)

let announcementString = NSAttributedString(string: "something",
                                            attributes: [queueAnnouncementKey : NSNumber(booleanLiteral: true)])

UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification, announcementString)
```

## Problem:

- The announcement is not queued, if there is an on going announcement at that moment, it ignores my announcement

## Possible Cause:

- I think something the way I create `NSAttributedString` is wrong
- I think the `NSAttributedString` has changed from the time this presentation was made, so needed to use rawValue.
- May be it is because it is not the correct raw value and that is causing it not to work.

## Refer:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017-215/?time=1627

https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2017/215avg3cuo2bu/215/215_whats_new_in_accessibility.pdf?dl=1

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry, your code is correct with your `annoucementString`.

However, you should read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51732172/how-can-i-queue-multiple-accessibility-notifications-for-voiceover/52459406#52459406) to understand the use cases why it doesn't work as you want because the system takes over when needs be and  all the queued announcements are removed then.